# Acquire direct write access to window's backbuffer, yet still allow read access to what is on the screen already

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

I was wondering; is it possible to acquire write access to the graphics card's primary buffer though the windows api, yet still allow read access to what *should* be there? To clarify, here is what I want:

1. Create a directx device on a window
   and hide it. Use the stencil buffer
   to apply an alpha channel to pixels
   not written to by my code.
2. Acquire the entirety
   of current display adapter's buffer.
   I.e. have a pointer to a buffer, in
   the current bit depth and
   resolution, that contains the
   current screen *without* whatever I
   drew to the screen. I was thinking
   of, instead of hiding my window,
   simply use a LAYERED window and
   somehow acquire the buffer before my
   window's pixels get blitted to it.
3. Copy the buffer acquired in step 2 into a new memory location
4. Blit my directx's device's primary buffer to the buffer built in step 3
5. Blit the buffer in step 4 to the screen
6. GOTO 2

So the end result is drawing hardware accelerated 3D directly to the window's desktop while still rendering other applications.

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways to create a window without borders. You might try experimenting with the [dwStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632600%28VS.85%29.aspx) parameter of [CreateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679%28VS.85%29.aspx), for example. It looks as if you pass in WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_POPUP and it results in a borderless window, which is what you appear to want. (see [this forum post](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=418170)).

I also think the term "borderless window" is not correct, because I'm hardly getting any results in Google for searches including those words.

Answer (score -1):

Is there any reason why you wouldn't just do this normally with GDI and use windowed mode for DirectX? Why bother with full-screen mode when you need to render with a window?